# $('tr:even').addClass('alt');

Tags: jquery

why does `$('tr:even').addClass('alt');` select from the 1st row 
and `$('tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('alt');` selects from the 2nd row ?

Answer (score 8):

It's because :even gets even elements using 0-based indexing and :nth-child() uses 1-based indexing.

Comment: then why $('tr:even').addClass('alt') selects index 1, should not it select index 2 (Even)?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the selector looks at the index and nth-child(even) looks at the length? Seems like an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

got it! :odd and :even selectors use Javascript native zero based numbering. so the first row counts as 0(even)